# UIDatePicker just showing weekdays, days and months

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I want a `UIDatePicker` just showing the day of the weeks and the days/months.
I tried `UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime` which shows the weekday but also the hours.

[image]

And `UIDatePickerMode.Date` which doesn't show the weekdays:
[image]

I want like .Date but with Weekdays

Comment: This is not possible with default `UIDatePicker`, you should try some other custom date picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieved using customization. here are some links of sample code having customize picker. you can take reference of its.

[Daydatepickerview](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/daydatepickerview)

[hsdatepickerviewcontroller](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hsdatepickerviewcontroller)

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with `UIDatePicker`,you can do it with `UIPickerView`

Answer (score 1):

this is exactly and even more than what you need :)

https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0